# Spreading Radio buttons using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap grid system for radio buttons and I am trying to spread them out to not look so jammed into each other. Will someone please assist me in how to do this with the grid system setup?

This is what I have tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/75qmj037/11/

```
<div id="ownership" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="MCO" />Manufacturer's statement of origin</label>
        <label class='radiolabel'>
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" />Florida certificate of title</label>
        <label class='radiolabel'>
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" />Out-of-state certificate of title</label>
        <label class='radiolabel'>
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>
    <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
    <label for="ownership" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This should work for bootstrap 3.x :*

Should be able to put each of them in a div like `<div col-lg-2>`. Note the `lg` you've used will only display it like this on desktops, if you want it the same on all devices use `xs` or else specify different columns for each screen size instead `sm` and `md`.

```
<div id="ownership" class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="MCO" />Manufacturer's statement of origin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" />Florida certificate of title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" />Out-of-state certificate of title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>
        </div>
        <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
        <label for="ownership" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do i put <div col-lg-2> in side the <div col-lg-12> ?

Comment: I did show with code in a way. I can do out an example. Yea can do. You could also remove the original column and put them in individual columns

Comment: Updated. Try that mate

Answer (score 1):

well , here I put every single radio in **col-md-4** grid with it's label. which means in the medium screen will show 3 of them.
if you want to show them all you can make it **col-md-3** which means show 4 of them in medium screen

```
   <div id="ownership" class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="MCO" />Manufacturer's statement of origin</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" />Florida certificate of title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" />Out-of-state certificate of title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>
                </div>
        <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
        <label for="ownership" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add :

```
 .radiolabel input {
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```css
 .radiolabel input {
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ownership" class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class='radiolabel'>
      <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="MCO" />Manufacturer's statement of origin</label>
      <label class='radiolabel'>
      <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" />Florida certificate of title</label>
      <label class='radiolabel'>
      <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" />Out-of-state certificate of title</label>
      <label class='radiolabel'>
      <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>
     <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
     <label for="ownership" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="ownership" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6">

                <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="MCO" />Manufacturer's statement of                          origin</label>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" />Florida certificate of title</label>
           </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" />Out-of-state certificate of title</label>
           </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class='radiolabel'>
            <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
        <label for="ownership" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably should do the work. try it out

```
#ownership .radiolabel input[type="radio"] {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:4px; /*or whatever distance from buttom to text*/
margin-left:4px; /*if you want to add some space at the left of the radio button also*/
    }
```